# Reputation value under Meta Participation is misleading

Tags: bug, statistics, moderator-election

Reputation shouldn't appear under "Meta Participation" since the reputation value it shows was earned on Stack Overflow not Meta.

I understand that a user's Meta reputation is just the same as the main site's reputation.  But why even include a Reputation stat under Meta Participation? I could understand if the Reputation value was calculated based on Meta.SO, then it could be useful, but it's not.

So I'd suggest removing that all together, ***or*** putting reputation underneath the Statistics column, ***or*** figure out what their actual meta.SO rep would be if it were calculated like any other site.

For an example, here is what Moshe's looks like on [this page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow)

[image]

Comment: I think that for that specific page you are correct - there is no point showing the Meta reputation. IIRC that layout pre-dates the MetaSO/MetaSE split, back then the reps between SO and MetaSO were separate so it did mean something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the MSO/MSE split happened most of the special-casing code was removed, but it seems that this slipped through the cracks (strictly, it's [due to caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) I think, but…) as [slugster suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289510/reputation-value-under-meta-participation-is-misleading#comment173369_289510).

The reputation entry has now been removed from that column completely, thanks for pointing that out!